# Package shortcut to "dist" folder for TypeScript and Yarn workspace

Tags: typescript, node-modules, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to create a yarn workspace by letting 2 apps share local packages. In my `next` app, I can reference the shared module using:

```
import logger from "@acme/utils/dist/src/logger"
```

However, I would like to reference it like this:

```
import logger from "@acme/utils/logger"
```

This is what my `utils/tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And my tree structure:

```
workspace/
├─ nest/
├─ next/
├─ shared/
   ├─ utils/
      ├─ src
         ├─ logger.ts
```

I believe I can achieve this creating a `index.ts` file in the package `src` directory with all the exports in there, then expose this `index.ts` as the main entry point as this:

```
"main": "./dist/index.js",
"types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
```

However, this seems like a lot of manual work as I add more more modules to my `util` package. I also stumbled upon adding this to my package.json and worked:

```
"exports": {
  "./*": "./dist/*"
},
"typesVersions": {
  "*": {
    "*": ["dist/*"]
  }
}
```

Is using `typesVersion` not recommended? I'm using Node 18. I tried without `typesVersion` but it wouldn't build.

Is there a correct way to only use `exports` for this without using a root `index.ts` or the `typeVersion` key? Any help or experience is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to add

```json
"files": [
    "dist"
]
```

to your `package.json`?

*The `files` field is an array of files to include in your project. If you name a folder in the array, then it will also include the files inside that folder.*